# How to pass form field without filling in Django? And add extra field to for answer?

Tags: django

I wanna make patient information register form. I did model.py and form.py but, when i come to use, i couldn't pass the form without filling. Forexample, in this image evlilik tarihi means marriage date, evlilik tarihi 2 means second marriage date, when i filling the form i want to leave empty the evlilik tarihi 2 field. But always i took this error "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'"
I used null=True, blank=True, but nothing. How can i pass the form field without filling.

And second question is, i made three form field for multiple marriage but is there any way how can i add button to this marriage field, and someone had second or third marriage, he can easily add button and give marriage date to me. How can i do this?

Form.py

```
class HastaBilgiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = HastaBilgi
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'hasta_ad_soyad' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hasta_dogum_tarihi' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), 
            'hasta_dogum_yeri' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'evlilik_tarihi_1' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'evlilik_tarihi_2' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'evlilik_tarihi_3' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'bosanma_tarihi_1' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'bosanma_tarihi_2' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'bosanma_tarihi_3' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'ogrenim_durumu' : forms.Select(choices=choices2, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'meslek' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'kan_grubu' : forms.Select(choices=choices1, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'boy' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'kilo' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'max_kilo' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'max_kilo_tarih' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'nereden_geldi' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'onceki_homeopati_tedavisi' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'gelis_sikayeti' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        
        }
```

Model.py

```
class HastaBilgi(models.Model):
    hasta_ad_soyad = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hasta_dogum_tarihi = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hasta_dogum_yeri = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    evlilik_tarihi_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    evlilik_tarihi_2 = models.DateField()
    evlilik_tarihi_3 = models.DateField()
    bosanma_tarihi_1 = models.DateField()
    bosanma_tarihi_2 = models.DateField()
    bosanma_tarihi_3 = models.DateField()
    ogrenim_durumu = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    meslek = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    kan_grubu = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    boy = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    kilo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    max_kilo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    max_kilo_tarih = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nereden_geldi = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    onceki_homeopati_tedavisi = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gelis_sikayeti = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hasta_ad_soyad
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to update your model.

```
evlilik_tarihi_2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

etc.  When you have made those changes you will need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow all fields from "red box" from image to be blank and nullable.
In your case:

```
class HastaBilgi(models.Model):
    ... # some staff before
    evlilik_tarihi_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    evlilik_tarihi_2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    evlilik_tarihi_3 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    bosanma_tarihi_1 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    bosanma_tarihi_2 = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ... # some staff after
```

don't forget to run this command in command line:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and after it:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

By the way, you mix in `evlilik_tarihi` `data` and `text` fields. It can be really confusing after some time, especially if you override it to text-widget instead of data-widget.

Comment: @mark-bailey and maxim-danilov thanks for your help. Both of them true. Thank you very much.